# MySql UNION SELECT is missing fields

Tags: mysql, union, mysql-error-1222

I'm, getting more and more frustrated because I don't understand why in my SELECT with UNION I am missing some fields.
I read good documentation about this and I followed the most common example avoiding getting different number of columns between the first and the second SELECT.

It consists in adding NULL columns reaching an even-number of columns between the two statements.

Here my case:

```
$query = "(SELECT GC.GroupNO AS GroupNO,
    GC.Name AS Name,
    GC.Pax AS Pax,
    GC.Start AS Start,
    NULL AS custid,
    NULL AS firstname,
    NULL AS lastname,
    NULL AS arrivaldate,
    NULL AS hour,
    NULL AS pax,
    NULL AS cctype,
    NULL AS created,
    NULL AS sid,
    NULL AS ref_source,
    NULL AS numnights
  FROM LargeGroupHostels, GroupContacts AS GC
   WHERE LargeGroupHostels.HostelNumber = %d
   AND LargeGroupHostels.Status = %s
   AND LargeGroupHostels.GroupNO = GC.GroupNO";
   AND GC.Start < %s
   ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC LIMIT %d, %d
   )UNION(
    SELECT
    NULL AS GroupNO,
    NULL AS Name,
    NULL AS Pax,
    NULL AS Start,
    `custid`,
    `firstname`,
    `lastname`,
    `arrivaldate`,
    `hour`,
    `pax`,
    `cctype`,
    `created`,
    `sid`,
    `ref_source`,
    datediff(departdate, arrivaldate) AS numnights
    FROM customer_details
    WHERE hostelnumber = %d
    AND lastupdated = "" AND status != "CANX"
    AND booking_type IN ("HOSTEL", "HOSTELPACK")
    ORDER BY customer_details.arrivaldate, customer_details.created
    LIMIT %d, %d )
    ';
```

Apart from some optimisations and some changes that I'm aware to do, my question here is:
 - Why don't I get the columns `GC.Name,GC.Pax,GC.Start`? If I reverse the two SELECTs, it happens exactly the opposite considering only `GC.Name,GC.Pax,GC.Start` and avoiding the other columns.

I'm not so practice about this kind of query and it is the first time for me handling this. I'm sure I'm missing something but I don't understand what

Comment: I may be missing something here - but why are you using a union for this? Union is for multiple queries having the same data structure. This looks like you're combining hostel data with customer data in single results, which can be done with any variety of joins and likely produce more readable results

Comment: First query has `groupno`, second query has `numnights` and they don't line up.

Comment: @KaiQing you have reason but in this case the record will be arranged in a single array because they have a lot in common even if the names may suggest differently. The problem is that I get a very big array and I need to paginate the result improving the performance at the meantime. I have tried using the array_slice for the pagination but the problem of loading the records of course keeps existing

Comment: How dynamic does the query need to be? You could process the data inefficiently and cache the results in flat text, or look into the more complex stored procedures, but I can't really advise on that. Nothing's faster or more efficient than static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to UNION for example `GC.name` with `Name`.  These are interpreted as two separate columns by MySQL as it has no way to intelligently guess at your intent (and probably shouldn't have that ability).  You should alias the column names in the first SELECT statement that do not currently have aliases like so:

```
SELECT GC.GroupNO AS GroupNO,
GC.Name AS Name,
GC.Pax AS Pax,
GC.Start AS Start,
```

In all other cases your aliases or raw column names match.

I would also agree with one of the comments above that this is likely better suited for a JOIN of some sort.

Comment: That's true but I tried also that solution but it doesn't work. I have updated the query in the original issue as you suggested

Comment: @RobertoRizzi So what result do you get now?  I don't see how you would have "missing" columns in the case where are columns match exactly from both SELECT statements.

Comment: Well, var dumping the GroupNO or Pax for eg i get NULL, conversely var dumping custid it shows up correctly :(

Comment: @RobertoRizzi You are going to get NULL values on some fields on every row.  You are introducing that by design in both SELECT statements. I thought your problem was with columns missing from the union, now it seems like your question might be related to unexpected results being returned by the underlying subqueries.  Can you at least confirm that with this change that you are getting all columns you expect in the result set?

Comment: I understand but my question now would be whether there would be a way to mix up those tables in a single query and then paginate it. Originally they were two separate queries pushing up the results in one array and then listed. It came up that after a while data increased and now it is very slow in loading and more time passes, much slower it becomes

Comment: @RobertoRizzi That would be a different question altogether. A much more complex one and one that would likely require you to show more information around your database schema, sample data from pertinent tables, and an example and explanation of your desired result set.  You should consider opening that as a different question on SO if you have problem doing this all though JOINs, which is what you sound like you want to do.  If we have solved the missing columns problem, at a minimum, you should accept an answer and close out the question as it still has possible value to future readers.

Comment: @RobertoRizzi With regards to your "slowness" problem, again I think you need to first look at how you can get to the desired result set using JOINs where all columns used in join criteria, filtering criteria, grouping, and ordering all have appropriate indexes.  Who knows, you may have problem with the design of your underlying schema that may prevent you from getting an optimized result.

Answer (score 0):

seem the position of the column are not the same

```
$query = "(SELECT GC.GroupNO,
GC.Name,
 .....
NULL AS ref_source
FROM LargeGroupHostels, GroupContacts AS GC
```

and

```
SELECT
   NULL AS Name,

  ....

  datediff(departdate, arrivaldate) as numnights
  FROM customer_details
```

in the firts select in first column you have a column  not present in second select  and in the second you have column at the end not matc with the firts select

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have fixed the query as you suggested but it keeps not taking the records `GC.GroupNO, GC.Name, GC.Pax,GC.Start`

Comment: You have a join in first select but I don't see the on clause ..FROM LargeGroupHostels, GroupContacts AS GC ....is right ..?

Comment: Column ordering has no impact on the UNION.

Comment: @scaisEdge yeah that's one of the improvements that it would need.
The join is in the WHERE clause ` AND LargeGroupHostels.GroupNO = GC.GroupNO`